# How to Enable SageMaker Debugger in the SageMaker AutoPilot

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-machine-learning

I'd like to (a) plot SHAP values out of the SageMaker (b) AutoML pipeline. To achieve (a), debugger shall be used according to: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/ml-explainability-with-amazon-sagemaker-debugger/.

But how to enable the debug model in the AutoPilot without hacking into the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SageMaker Autopilot doesn't support SageMaker Debugger out of the box currently (as of Dec 2020). You can hack the Hyperparameter Tuning job to pass in a debug parameter.

However, there is a way to use SHAP with Autopilot models. Take a look at this blog post explaining how to use SHAP with SageMaker Autopilot: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/explaining-amazon-sagemaker-autopilot-models-with-shap/.